# MySQL - make a weekly report that includes starting day (twist: week starting wednesday)

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I have this kind of table with time based data:

```
| entity_id | ttime               | value |
-------------------------------------------
|         1 | 2014-11-01 00:00:04 |   553 |
|         1 |                 ... |   600 |
|         2 |                 ... |   234 |
```

I want to get the average of the value grouped by week and entity_id. But I would like also the starting day of the week to appear in the results. Additional complexity is that the week starts on wednesday.

I can group by YEAR(ttime + INTERVAL 3 DAY), WEEK(ttime + INTERVAL 3 DAY) but is it possible to print the first day of the group (wednesday) in the results?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
 `entity_id`, 
  DATE_SUB(ttime, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(ttime)-2 DAY),
  SUM(`value`)  
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY `entity_id`, YEARWEEK(ttime + INTERVAL 4 DAY)
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5243dc/10)

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
SELECT
str_to_date(CONCAT(YEAR(ttime + INTERVAL -3 DAY), 
           WEEK(ttime + INTERVAL -3 DAY), 'Wednesday'), '%X%V %W') as WeekCommencing,
           entity_id, AVG(value), 
FROM `table`
GROUP BY WeekCommencing, entity_id
```